# Cannot install latest R version on Google Cloud

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform, rstudio, ubuntu-18.04, gcloud

I am trying to set up Rstudio on an Ubuntu cloud server (gcloud). I currently have version R-3.4.4 on RStudio, but would like to upgrade. The issue is, I am unable to.

I am running the following version of Ubuntu.

```
name@sc1:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I installed the RStudio server for Ubuntu 18 as suggested here: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/debian-ubuntu/

So essentially running to install the server:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-server-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.4.1717-amd64.deb
```

Checking the version of R Studio I have:

```
sudo -i R
```

Output:

```
name@sc1:~$ sudo -i R

R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

However, this is what pops up in my RStudio.
[image]

Anyone have ideas for what I'm doing wrong? How can I upgrade my package?

Furthermore, in my `/home/user/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library` directory, I have an R-3.4 folder, which is confusing…

Comment: In RStudio...Global Options...General...Basic, you can change which version of R is used by RStudio. Make sure that's pointing to the place where you installed R 4.1

Comment: Only find R 3.4 there. Seems that I might not have installed 4.1 after all?

Comment: Well, if you run `which R` is that the same as `sudo -i which R`? That should give the path to the R program in use. If that's the path where R 4.1 is installed, then you should be able to enter that path into the box in the RStudio configuration. You can compare that path to the one that appears in RStudio if you run `normalizePath(R.home())` in the console. I'm surprised you have to run `sudo` to run R. I don' think that should be necessary.

Comment: Both normalizePath and which R point to the same place, which appears to be R 3.4. Do you suggest i remove R and reinstall?

Comment: But `sudo -i which R` is different? I don't understand how `sudo -i R` would be returning "R version 4.1.0 " while the others do not. Note that when you just run `R` that's different than running `RStudio` which is an IDE for R. I'm also a bit confused as to whether you are running RStudio or RStudio server -- those are different things. And you seem to be referencing two different machines here with `scinstance` and `sc1`.

Comment: `normalizePath(R.home())`, `sudo -i which R` and `sudo -i R` return the same thing - /usr/bin/R.

Comment: Then I don't understand how you got the "R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- Camp Pontanezen" you've shown above. Because it doesn't sound like R 4.1 is installed on that machine. you must be working with two different machines.

Comment: I think you're right. Thank you.

Comment: can you delete the directory you are using and create as new one? as mentioned in the link : https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-version-mismatch-between-client-and-connect-server/111840

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that after I installed R 4.0, I had to restarted the VM and that seemed to work. Unclear why this is, but at least it worked!